# Meeting Notice Being Sent Even Though I Have Set Cancel in Item_Write

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I'm setting the Cancel check in the Item_Write event handler for a meeting request because if I set the Cancel to true in Item_Send, the meeting window closes. What I'm trying to do is prompt the user that they have recipients that would normally get processed using a custom button in the ribbon (button details not important for my question).  Anyway, when I try to Cancel the Item_Write event a meeting notice is sent regardless. No matter what I try, I cannot stop the meeting notice from going out even though I'm setting the ref Cancel to true. If I cancel on Item_Send then the window closes, which is not what the users want.  The only thing I can think of at this point is perhaps the                     requestDetailsRegion.SaveRequestDetailsToLocalOutlookItemProperties(), which saves custom form region field properties to defined custom properties on the AppointmentItem, is triggering the Application_Item_Load event and this somehow is prompting Outlook to send the meeting invite notice, as if it's pending. I'm running this in Outlook 2010. Thank you in advance.

Here's some example code:

```
  void Item_Write(ref bool Cancel)        
 {    

            Cancel = CancelInvite(Cancel);                
 }

        private bool CancelInvite(bool Cancel)
        {

            Inspector activeInspector = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector();
            WindowFormRegionCollection formRegions = Globals.FormRegions[activeInspector];
            RequestDetailsFormRegion requestDetailsRegion = formRegions.RequestDetailsForm;


                // Add request form details to meeting item.
                requestDetailsRegion.SaveRequestDetailsToLocalOutlookItemProperties();

                // Checking if there's an incomplete form request pending submission
                if (requestDetailsRegion.txtFileName_Hidden.TextLength == 0 &&
                    appointmentItem != null && appointmentItem.MeetingStatus != OlMeetingStatus.olMeetingCanceled)
                {
                    Persons meetingRecipients = new Persons();



                    foreach (Outlook.Recipient recipient in appointmentItem.Recipients)
                        if (recipient.Address != activeInspector.Session.CurrentUser.Address)
                            meetingRecipients.Add(new MeetingRecipient(recipient));

                    if (meetingRecipients.ContainsSpecialRecipients)
                    {                           
                        CustomDialog customDialog = new CustomDialog();
                        customDialog.OkButtonText = messageBoxTextStatusOK;
                        customDialog.CancelButtonText = messageBoxTextStatusCancel;

                        DialogResult dialogResult = customDialog.ShowDialog();

                        if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Cancel)
                        {
                            Cancel = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Cancel = false;
                        }    

                        customDialog.Close();
                    }
                }                

            return Cancel;
        }

   public void SaveRequestDetailsToLocalOutlookItemProperties()
        {
            if (this.OutlookItem is Outlook.AppointmentItem)
            {
                Outlook.AppointmentItem appointmentItem = (Outlook.AppointmentItem)this.OutlookItem;

                // Checking if organizer already cancelled meeting. If so, then no need to update apppointment item properties.
                if (appointmentItem.MeetingStatus != Outlook.OlMeetingStatus.olMeetingCanceled)
                {

                    appointmentItem.ItemProperties[RequestSubmitted].Value = chkSubmitted.Checked; // Hidden 
                    appointmentItem.ItemProperties[Filename].Value = txtFileName_Hidden.Text; // Hidden

                    appointmentItem.ItemProperties[ReasonForVisit].Value = txtReason.Text;

   // SPARING SIMILAR LINES OF CODE

    ...
                    chkSaved.Checked = true;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never set the (ref) Cancel parameter to true

```
void Item_Write(ref bool Cancel)        
 {    

            this.cancelInviteResult = CancelInvite(Cancel);
            Cancel = this.cancelInviteResult; 
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Dmitry. I actually do. I'm going to update the code example. It happens in spite of setting Cancel to true. Which is the precise issue that's driving me batty to begin with.

Comment: Just to clarify when I say "It happens...", the sending of the meeting notice happens in spite of setting Cancel to true. Thanks again.

Comment: What is your Application.ItemSend event handler?

Comment: Thanks for checking back Dmitry. As for what's currently in Application.ItemSend...nothing. But before I had the CancelInvite check in Application.ItemSend, but when Cancel == true it prevents the request notice from being sent but abruptly closes the window. Users want to be taken back to meeting request form if they select "Don't Send" from dialog box. Sorry that I neglected to include this in my question. I'll update accordingly.

Comment: I'm going to put the call to the cancel check function back in ItemSend, but this time see if I can cancel the closing of the window. I think this is the only sensible route I can take at this point before telling the users that this requirement can't be met.

Comment: Hi Dmitry. I just received a new machine, ran code to set ref Cancel to true and everything worked fine. The Inspector didn't mysteriously close like on my other machine. I'm going to check off your answer. However, I'm still dumbfounded on the Window closing after setting Cancel to true on Item_Send handler when running on my previous machine. That's for another day. :) Cheers.